# #here i did't pass the visited list so it should start with default False list but its not?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, graph-traversal

I have Created a graph but it has the above problem as issued in the title

Basically what i am trying to do is dfs traversal in the graph using adjancency matrix

```
class Graph:
    def _init_(self,vertices):
    self.vertices = vertices 
    self.adjMatrix = [[0 for _ in range(self.vertices)] for _ in range(self.vertices)]

def addEdge(self,v1,v2):
    self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 1
    self.adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 1

def removeEdge(self,v1,v2):
    self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] = 0
    self.adjMatrix[v2][v1] = 0

def containEdge(self,v1,v2):
    return True if self.adjMatrix[v1][v2] > 0 else False

def _str_(self) -> str:
    return str(self.adjMatrix)

def __dfs_helper(self,sv,visited):
    print(sv)
    visited[sv] = True 

test = Graph(5)
test.addEdge(0,1)
test.addEdge(0,4)
test.addEdge(1,3)
test.addEdge(2,3)
test.addEdge(3,4)

def dfs(test,vertex,visited = [False for _ in range(test.vertices)]):
    print(visited,vertex)
    matrix = test.adjMatrix 
    if visited[vertex]:
        return 
    visited[vertex] = True 
    #print(visited,vertex)
    for x in range(len(matrix[vertex])):#  x is the next vertex
        if matrix[vertex][x] == 1 and visited[x] is False:
            dfs(test,x,visited)
(dfs(test,0))
#works fine above
dfs(test,0)

#here i did't pass the visited list so it should start with default False list but its not?
```

Comment: Don't use [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)

Comment: 1/ The title is not informative. 2/ Indentation seems wrong. 2/ The description of the problem needs to be clarified.